# primefaces menu disappearing fast issue in mozilla

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

primefaces submenu are disappearing fast when i am putting cursor on menu. but same menu's not disappearing in chrome and IE.  let me know what will be the work around for the same.  for e.g  http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menu/menubar.xhtml  check the issue for edit menu in above link - mozi

Comment: menu disappears in a blink of second, when we move cursor on it

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome Version 43.0.2357.65 m, Firefox 38.0.1 and IE 11.0.9600.17801 the p:menubar showcase works as intended. 
For a better analysis we need more information about your environment. 
Browser Versions, PrimeFaces-Version, if you use Custom-CSS or primefaces-default, etc. 
Everything you think is helpful.
With the current information we can't help you.

Comment: mozilla version: 31.7.0
primefaces version :5.0

Comment: i am using few custom css and even tried to over ride widget to increase font-size so that it will work with mozilla. but unable to override

Comment: Installed the 31.7.0 ESR to test the showcase, works as usual. In earlier PrimeFaces Versions (somewhere around 3.0) there were CSS-issues with Internet-Explorer that triggered the behavior you described. Play around with the font-size of the menu-items, decreasing it fixed it in earlier versions.
To override the primefaces css, you can either use !important in your css or use <f:facet name="last"> to load your css after the primefaces css.

Comment: Check browser zoom level to. Should be 0

Comment: @RagnarT: most important thing to get custom css applied is to use good selectors. CSS specificity is key here…  !important should not be needed (nor used) in most cases

Answer (score 0):

.ui-widget, .ui-widget .ui-widget {
    font-size: 13px!important;

}

above css code worked for me. if i put 12px issue still persists , don